# Где хранить данные о подключение к БД в git?

Tags: база-данных, git, github, gitlab

как в git можно реализовать сохранение данных о подключение к БД (а именно прокол, имя хоста, порт,имя уз для подлкючения и его пароль) в скрытом виде, чтобы это хранилось на локальном компьютере, а не в репозитории?

Comment: Что-то ваш вопрос противоречит сам себе. Хранить в git — значит в репозитории. Хранить только на локальном компьютере — значит не в git. Определитесь, что конкретно вам нужно-то

Comment: Нужно хранить данные о базе в не git, однако иметь возможность обращаться к данному файлу с целью отправления запроса к базе данных